# UART Communication: Usage of ODD and EVEN partiy

Tags: uart, serial-communication, error-detection

I am currently working on understanding UART communication. The parity bit is used to check for errors in the transmission, but why are there odd and even modes?

They serve the exact same use. One of the two modes would be enough. For instance, odd could be used all the time without issues, couldn't it?

Thanks for explanation.

Comment: Yes, but it's historical. There's no technical explanation, just different people did different things at different times.

Comment: It is simply because there are two choices and they are equally valid.  It doesn't matter which one you pick, as long as the machine and the device agree.  If you can decide then pick Even, it is less odd.

Answer (score 1):

If you use EVEN parity and if you on UART short-cut line to ground then all data bits and parity will be 0 and receiving side can understand that it is OK and receive 0x00. so from my point of view is in this case better ODD parity.

But also you can find opposite situations, where can be better to use EVEN parity